# PHP cache high use ram

Tags: php, caching

I am writing a caching class with php. It only consumes a lot of RAM. Why did not I solve it like that. I would be glad if you help me about this subject. Where can I make mistakes.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in Config.php on line 65

and I get the error above.

codes are that way.

```
class Cache {

    var $doNotCache = array("admin","profile");

    var $cacheDir = NULL;
    var $cacheTime = 21600;
    var $caching = false;
    var $cacheFile;
    var $cacheFileName;
    var $cacheLogFile;
    var $cacheLog;

    function __construct(){
        $this -> cacheDir = CACHE_DIR;
        $this -> cacheFile = md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $this -> cacheFileName = $this -> cacheDir.'/'.$this-> cacheFile. '.cache';
        $this -> cacheLogFile = $this -> cacheDir."/log.txt";
        if(!is_dir( $this-> cacheDir )) mkdir( $this-> cacheDir, 0755);
        if(file_exists($this->cacheLogFile))
            $this->cacheLog = unserialize(file_get_contents($this->cacheLogFile));
        else
            $this->cacheLog = array();

    }

    function start(){
        $location = array_slice(explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 2);
        if(!in_array($location[0],$this->doNotCache)){
            if(file_exists($this->cacheFileName) && (time() - filemtime($this->cacheFileName)) < $this->cacheTime && $this->cacheLog[$this->cacheFile] == 1){
                $this->caching = false;
                echo file_get_contents($this->cacheFileName);
                exit();
            }else{
                $this->caching = true;
                ob_start();
            }
        }
    }

    function end(){
        if($this->caching){
            file_put_contents($this->cacheFileName,ob_get_contents());
            ob_end_flush();
            $this->cacheLog[$this->cacheFile] = 1;
            if(file_put_contents($this->cacheLogFile,serialize($this->cacheLog)))
                return true;
        }
    }

    function purge($location){
        $location = base64_encode($location);
        $this->cacheLog[$location] = 0;
        if(file_put_contents($this->cacheLogFile,serialize($this->cacheLog)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    function purge_all(){
        if(file_exists($this->cacheLogFile)){
            foreach($this->cacheLog as $key=>$value) $this->cacheLog[$key] = 0;
            if(file_put_contents($this->cacheLogFile,serialize($this->cacheLog)))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

}
```

config.php

```
class Config {
    public static function Get($string = '') {
        global $Globals;
        if($string) {

            $config = $Globals['Config'];
            $string = explode('/', $string); // Error row.

            foreach ($string as $path) {
                if(isset($config[$path])) {
                    $config = $config[$path];
                }
            }
            return $config;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to unserialize a log file?

Comment: I throw in another variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily run out of memory if your log file grows large because your class tries to *read in and unserialize the entire log file.* As your code is currently written, that logFile could grow without bound -- you don't even bother writing any code to rotate the log when it gets large.

You should have told us specifically which line is getting the 'out of memory' error. I'm guessing this is the line that runs out of memory:

```
$this->cacheLog = unserialize(file_get_contents($this->cacheLogFile));
```

I'd strongly suggest that you don't ever read in the log file and try to parse it into an array. Instead, you should only ever append to a log. And if you want to avoid filling up your entire hard drive with a giant log file, you should write a proper logging function that will rotate your log files when they get too large.

Comment: you may be right about this, but I get this error in the log file without any data.

Comment: @APAWebBilişimHizmetleri can you identify which line of code is causing the 'out of memory' error? PHP should tell you which line it is and you can share it with us.

Comment: of course. Config.php on line 65. I updated my code.

Comment: That config.php code you posted doesn't have 65 lines. You need to try a little harder. E.g., post all the relevant code and identify the line that is causing the error.

Comment: I'm using the config class in many places. I do not think it originated from it.

Comment: I deleted the description lines. Line 65: $ string = explode ('/', $ string);

Comment: The Config::get function looks pretty whack too. You fetch $config from some global variable and then reassign $config to be some sub-element of that global config. But this probably will not tell us why you are running out of memory because this line is only trying to allocate 24 bytes. This line isn't your real problem. It's just the straw that breaks the camel's back.

Comment: I am experiencing such a problem when writing a cache class. Do you have an example that you can suggest?

Comment: @APAWebBilişimHizmetleri that is an entirely different question.